# why php tag is not working if i store and show it in wp_head?

Tags: wp-head

hi i used wp_head a couple of times.I echoed some values it works like below

```
function test()
{
echo "hello am visible";
}
add_action('wp_head','test');
```

but if i store a php code in db and retrieve it to a variable and echoed it is not working, 
here is the sample

```
<?php echo "i will go to db and come again"; ?>
```

i stored the above value in LONGTEXT format in db as `trial` then i selected the table and assigned it to a variable like below

```
$output = $result->trial;
```

Here come the problem part

```
function test()
    {
    //after retrieve 
    echo $output;
    }
add_action('wp_head','test');
```

this way it is not working.i can't able to see i will go to db and come again. What is the problem? Thanks

Comment: What do you see instead?

Comment: same <?php echo "i will go to db and come again"; ?> if i show it in div.but if i don't show it in div i can't able to see it.

Comment: Anything in `wp_head` won't be visible in the browser. You need to view the page source (Ctrl/Cmd+U)

Comment: i'm getting the same **<?php echo "i will go to db and come again"; ?>** code not the interpreted source

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to execute the PHP code. You'll need to use the [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) function. Though you really shouldn't be doing this…

Comment: Thanks.Do you have any idea on what happening in this code? like why it is not interpreting i already having it in hooking function so it should interpreted right?Why this is not happening? Thanks for eval() function

Comment: What code are you referring to?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10444/discussion-between-sun-and-bungeshea)

Comment: Why do you need to execute code in the header?

Comment: @ Mario there i will use few divs,images(path) designs to show in head